# PHP Laravel 6 @method("patch")

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь сделать на laravel 6 update базы данных конкретного пользователя.

Есть template:

```
<h2>Edit customer details</h2>

<form action="/customers/{customer}" method="post">

    @method('patch')

    <div>
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('name')}}">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" autocomplete="off" value="{{ old('email')}}">
    </div>

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    <button>Edit</button>

    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <p style="color: red">{{$error}}</p>
    @endforeach

</form>
```

Когда попадаю на эту страницу `@method("patch")` отображается в **html** как обычный текст между заголовком и input. А при попытке отправить форму выдаёт ошибку **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**. В чём проблема?

```
Edit customer details
@method('patch')
Name
Email
```

Comment: Роуты прописаны?

Comment: да, как бы я попал на эту страницу

Comment: Роут `put/patch` для `/customers/{customer}` тоже прописан правильно? Попробуйте почистить кэш роутов `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: в роутах проблем нет, не могу понят при чём тут @method("patch"), если они влияют только на переход страницы и вызов контроллера

Comment: @Aleks название шаблона прописано верно, через .blade? Ощущение что не работает шаблонизатор. Хотя, тогда бы не работали и foreach

Comment: @Aleks еще возможно какие директивы подключния шаблонов напутали, yield, include, section, extend

Comment: с шаблонизатором походу точно какие-то проблемы, у меня не работал csrf, здесь подсказали что нужно писать так csrf_field(), хотя название шаблонов и директивы прописаны правильно, была проблема с error, теперь та же проблема с method("patch"). А вот if и foreach работают без проблем с самого начала, может с настройками в laravel что-то не так?

Answer (score 0):

1. `{{ csrf_field() }}` заменить на `@csrf` и поместить его под открывающий тег `<form>` и над `@method('patch')`
2. замени `<button>` на нормальную кнопку `<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Edit">`
3. вынеси `@foreach` за пределы формы

Comment: {{ csrf_field() }} заменить не могу поскольку @csrf тоже не работает, спрашивал здесь дали такой совет, button и foreach не на что не влияют